# CUDA for pytorch: CUDA C++ stream and state

Tags: c++, cuda, pytorch

I am trying to follow [this tutorial](https://pytorch.org/tutorials/advanced/cpp_extension.html) and make a simple c++ extension with CUDA backend.
My CPU implementation seems to work fine.

I am having trouble finding examples and documentation (it seems like things are constantly changing).

Specifically,

1. I see pytorch cuda functions getting `THCState *state` argument - where does this argument come from? How can I get a `state` for my function as well?
   For instance, in cuda implementation of [`tensor.cat`](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/blob/master/aten/src/THC/generic/THCTensorMath.cu#L44):

   > ```
   > void THCTensor_(cat)(THCState *state, THCTensor *result, THCTensor *ta, THCTensor *tb, int dimension)
   > ```

   However, when calling `tensor.cat()` from python one does not provide any `state` argument, pytorch provides it "behind the scene". How pytorch provides this information and how can I get it?
2. `state` is then converted to `cudaStream_t stream = THCState_getCurrentStream(state);`
   For some reason, `THCState_getCurrentStream` is no longer defined? How can I get the `stream` from my `state`?

I also tried asking on [pytorch](https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/cuda-c-stream-and-state/42713) forum - so far to no avail.

Comment: Both of your questions seen like PyTorch internals which are probably only going to be answered by reading the code

Comment: @talonmies I added a bit of reference code. I hope it helps. But you are right, I suspect this question requires some knowledge on the internal mechanism of pytorch...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's deprecated (without documentation!)
See here:
https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/pull/14500

In short: use `at::cuda::getCurrentCUDAStream()`